# nth-child for img tag within a div tag and a tag

Tags: css, css-selectors

i'm trying to have the nth number of img in the div to not have a right border as illustrated in the jsfiddle below.

have a look here:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SYEWS/2/)

i tried with this but it doesnt work either

```
.intro img:nth-child(3n+0)
{
border-right:none !important;
}
```

i got it to work successfully without having the image in the 'a' tag.
but i need it inside.

any idea how i can make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.intro a:nth-child(3n) img
```

It is the `a` that is the `nth-child` not the `img`.

http://jsfiddle.net/SYEWS/4/

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use just

```
.intro a:last-child img{
    border-right: none;

}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SYEWS/3/)

Comment: ah ha. but i was just trying to get say the 3rd or 4th img in the div. james posted the answer i needed but nonetheless i didnt know about last child before this. thanks too!

Comment: then you could use .intro a:nth-child(3) img just